# How to set the default indent width to 4 when formatting?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, format

I am using the extension `clang-format` in vscode to format my `c` and `cpp` files. Followed by the instructions on the internet, i set the setting file like below, but i can't figure out how to change the default indent width.

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
"clang-format.style": "Google",
"clang-format.language.c.enable": true,
"clang-format.language.cpp.enable": true,
"clang-format.executable": "/usr/bin/clang-format-12",
"[c]": {
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "xaver.clang-format",
   "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
   "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace",
   "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
},
"[cpp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "xaver.clang-format"
}
}
```

Comment: [Default settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings) of vscode for `tabsize` is `4`

Comment: What i want to achieve is when formatting , not clicking the tab , the indent size will be 4

Answer (score 0):

```json
"clang-format.style": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4}"
```

All extension options are described here [vscode-clang-format-provider/package.json](https://github.com/xaverh/vscode-clang-format-provider/blob/master/package.json).

All clang-format style options are described here [Clang-Format Style Options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).